# Undefined function or variable 'DataMatrix'

Tags: matlab, datamatrix

I was trying to create a DataMatrix variable by calling the DataMatrix() function.
But that function doesn't exist. If I type this:

```
>> DataMatrix
```

I got this error message:

```
Undefined function or variable 'DataMatrix'.
```

I did install the Bioinformatics Toolbox and my version is 2016b on Mac

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the only explanation is that your toolbox hasn't been installed properly (such as not being on the [MATLAB path](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html)). There's not much we can do to help you without more info.

Comment: @gnovice Could be a coincidence but I can reproduce his error. Using `exist` also gives `0`. Completing the name using tab also doesn't give me anything. Furthermore, `help DataMatrix` gives `DataMatrix not found` but `doc DataMatrix` opens its documentation. I can also reproduce this error with other functions of the Bioinformatics Toolbox such as `dmarrayfun`, `dmwrite` etc. (R2016a on Win10)

Comment: I have voted to reopen, this is a legit question, nothing to do with "undefined functions" or "badly installed package". The DataMatrix class is enclosed in a "Package" / Namespace and needs to be accessed accordingly. On my installation it's the `bioma` package, which contains a `data` subpackage, which contains the class. To create an instance you will either have to type something like  `D = bioma.data.DataMatrix([1,2;3,4])` or `import bioma.data.DataMatrix` `D = DataMatrix([2,3;4,5])`. Yours is likely the same, but check your installation just in case. I'll give more details if re-opened.

Comment: Note that what @Tasos is talking about is [clearly written in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/datamatrix.html) which I found by googling "matlab datamatrix".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>As @Andras mentioned in the comments, the procedure to import and use this class is already [mentioned in the documentation for the class](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/datamatrix.html#brrxzs7-3) (though you might be forgiven if you missed it, as it's not on the top part of the page dealing with syntax).</sub>

---

**The tl;dr version is that you should either access the class constructor as, e.g.:**

```
D = bioma.data.DataMatrix(...);
```

**or, [import](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html?searchHighlight=import&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) the class from the package / namespace first, and then use it directly, i.e.:**

```
import bioma.data.DataMatrix;
D = DataMatrix(...);
```

---

**Explanation**

The reason you need this step in the first place, is because this class is enclosed inside a "package" (a.k.a. a "namespace"). Read the section called "[Packages Create Namespaces](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html?searchHighlight=packages&s_tid=doc_srchtitle)" in the matlab documentation to find out more what this means.

However, in principle it boils down to the fact that, if you have a folder whose name has a `+` prefix, then this acts as a namespace for the functions contained within.

So, if you have a folder called `+MyPackage` on your path, and this contains a function m-file called `myfunction.m` (but this is not in your path), then you can access this function in the matlab terminal by typing `MyPackage.myfunction()`.

*Or*, you can `import MyPackage.myfunction` from that package / namespace and then use `myfunction` directly.

So, going back to `DataMatrix`, you will see that if you search where the class definition is located in your matlab folder, you'll find it here:

```
./toolbox/bioinfo/microarray/+bioma/+data/@DataMatrix/DataMatrix.m
```

and presumably `./toolbox/bioinfo/microarray` is already in your path.

I.e. the `bioma` package/namespace is in your path, and you can access the `data` package/namespace below it, and then the class definition for `DataMatrix` by doing `bioma.data.DataMatrix`.

---

<sub>PS: Furthermore, the "@" prefix in front of a folder name denotes a class folder, containing the constructor and class methods. If this "@folder" is in your path (or imported etc), then this means you have access to the underlying constructor. This is a remnant from [matlab's old object-oriented style](https://ubcmatlabguide.github.io/html/objectOrientedOldStyle.html), before the `classdef` keyword was introduced. You can read more about class directories [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html) if you're interested.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! Your

    import bioma.data.DataMatrix;

was what I was looking for